# Back button isn't clearing out previous template

Tags: ember.js

I'm building a simple demo, and everything seems to work except for one thing: navigating to a link then clicking the 'Back' button doesn't clear out the `company` template. Any ideas?

I've posted a jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dikud/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Ember is getting confused by some malformed html. I beleive the last `<p>` int the company template should be a `</p>` see http://jsbin.com/potujawa/2/